# toString (коллекции)

Tags: java

```
public class Car {

    String model;

    public Car(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "model='" + model + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}


public class Test {                                         
    public static void main(String[] args) {                
        LinkedList<Car> cars = new LinkedList<>();          
        Car ferrari = new Car("Ferrari 360 Spider");        
        Car bugatti = new Car("Bugatti Veyron");            
        Car lambo = new Car("Lamborghini Diablo");          
        Car ford = new Car("Ford Mondeo");                  
        Car fiat = new Car("Fiat Ducato");                  

        cars.add(ferrari);                                  
        cars.add(bugatti);                                  
        cars.add(lambo);                                    
        System.out.println(cars);                           

        cars.addFirst(ford);                                
        cars.addLast(fiat);                                 
        System.out.println(cars);                           
    }                                                       
}
```

Этот код выведет в консоль:

**`[Car{model='Ferrari 360 Spider'}`,** и тд.

Если удалить `toString()` метод в классе `Car`, то мы получим:

```
[Car@7c75222b, и тд.
```

Мне интересно одно, когда мы переопределили метод `toString()` в классе `Car` и он отрабатывал, но мы же не пишем `cars.toString()`, а просто `System.out.println(cars);` и это работает, как так?

Comment: Метод `println` вызывает `toString` переданного ему объекта.

Comment: `System.out.println` принимает на вход `Object`, чтобы привести его к строке `toString` вызывается автоматически

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В реализации метода println() обратите внимание на String s = String.valueOf(x);

```
 /**
 * Prints an Object and then terminate the line.  This method calls
 * at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value,
 * then behaves as
 * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(String)}</code> and then
 * <code>{@link #println()}</code>.
 *
 * @param x  The <code>Object</code> to be printed.
 */
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

а valueOf(x) в свою очередь вызывает .toString()

```
/**
 * Returns the string representation of the {@code Object} argument.
 *
 * @param   obj   an {@code Object}.
 * @return  if the argument is {@code null}, then a string equal to
 *          {@code "null"}; otherwise, the value of
 *          {@code obj.toString()} is returned.
 * @see     java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```